# How can I change default elements color android layout?

Tags: java, android, layout

I don't know how I changed in my app the default color for the different elements of the layout out such as RadioButton, Checkbox, etc. The now saw white and I have a white background. In normal layouts I can hack this by setting "buttonTint" of the element to the color I want, but in the preferences.xml (with PreferenceScreen layout) I can't do that.

This is what happens (See here = white checkbox):
[image]

I don't know what I've changed but I can't rollback. This is my styles.xml:

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorControlNormal">@color/white</item>
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:itemBackground">@color/white</item> <!-- Menu background color -->
    <item name="android:itemTextAppearance">@style/myCustomMenuTextAppearance</item>
</style>

<!-- Menu text color -->
<style name="myCustomMenuTextAppearance" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Widget.IconMenu.Item">
    <item name="android:textColor">#000</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="AnalyzeForeground" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Dialog">
    <item name="android:alertDialogStyle">@style/CustomAlertDialogStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">normal</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">12sp</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomAlertDialogStyle">
    <item name="android:bottomBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:bottomMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:centerMedium">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:fullDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topBright">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:topDark">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Edit

I add the color.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <color name="colorPrimary">#0098D6</color>
    <color name="colorPrimaryDark">#006e99</color>
    <color name="colorAccent">#0098D6</color>

    <color name="transparent_white_90">#F2FFFFFF</color>

    <color name="rating7">#ff6666</color>
    <color name="rating8">#ff0000</color>
    <color name="rating9">#990000</color>
    <color name="rating10">#800080</color>

    <color name="white">#FFF</color>

    <color name="background_transparent">#585858</color>
</resources>
```

Comment: check the `colorAccent` and check if it's white in the `colors.xml` file

Comment: @omar-al-halabi colors.xml added. `colorAccent` is the same as `colorPrimary`

Comment: you can also try using the theme editor to change the colors of elements. tools->android->theme editor.

Comment: @Simo I'm on the menu but I can't see where I can change the value when CheckBox is not checked

Comment: see [this](https://material.io/guidelines/style/color.html#color-color-system) for more

Comment: @Simo finally find out what was wrong. The value `colorControlNormal` of my AppTheme was set to white, I don't know why that attribute was set to white, but without that, solve the problem. Anyway thanks I didn't know anything about theme editor, but helps me to create a new one and detect the wrong attribute :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is you have used `colorControlNormal` as `white` color and it `overrides` the control `blue` color that you have defined as `colorAccent`.

**SOLUTION:**

Remove item `colorControlNormal` from `style` or give `colorControlNormal` a different `color`.

```
<item name="colorControlNormal">@color/colorAccent</item>
```

For details, see [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html):

```
colorControlNormal: The color applied to framework controls in their normal state.
```

Hope this will help~

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. If my answer seems helpful then please give an upvote. Read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use simple color resources, specified usually inside res/values/colors.xml.

```
<color name="red">#ffff0000</color>
```

and use via 
android:background="ffff0000"